# Custom Increment by given array in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have array like this

```
Array ( [0] => F [1] => F [2] => N [3] => )
```

How to run the two loops with above array ?

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) {
    //In this loop i need the output like above 
            F-01
            F-02
    }
```

I have an loop im fetching some data in it like

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 1; $x++) {
//In this loop i need the output like above 

        N-01

}
```

Comment: if my answer is really help you then please correct it out so it will help to other who have problem like you,

Answer (score 1):

For that on you need to do something like below

```
<?php

$myarray = Array ( 'F' ,'F' ,'N' , 'l');

$j =0;

for($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++ ){
  echo $myarray[$x].'-'.$j.$x; 
echo "<br>";
}
echo "<br>";


$m=0;
for($k=2;$k<=3;$k++){
  echo $myarray[$k].'-'.$j.$m;
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

I hope this will help you.